# TCP Port listener not working

Tags: c#, sockets, tcplistener

I need to connect a handheld with a PC. So I'm following [this MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397809.aspx) which has a Client and a Server program.

Now, the handheld is connected through GPRS. If I run the Client program on the handheld and listen to the port on the PC, I see the data that the handheld send. But if I run the Server program it doesn't receive anything.

My code follows the example exactly, only modifying the port in both programs(11000) and in the client I changed the server IP to my public address.

Why am I seeing the data in my TCP listener but not in my Server program?

Comment: Possible software firewall blocking by application?

Comment: Running as administrator or less privileged account?

Comment: I'm debugging my code with Visual Studio. I suppose that the firewall shouldn't block that, don't it?

Comment: Incoming firewall rules are different then outgoing firewall rules.  I'm pretty sure if you did not change anything than port numbers this is a firewall issue.

Comment: I disable the windows firewall. And In the router I already add a rule to this. There's any other firewall rule I should change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the Server Code. When configuring the IPAddress it wasn't creating a correct one.

I changed this line by this one and everything is working ok now:

```
IPAddress ipAddress = new IPAddress(new byte[] { 192, 168, 1, 10 });
```

Hope it help to another facing the same problem!